# How to import GUI class with Python class and connect methods

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have decided to use QT Designer from PyQt5 to make a visual interface of my app. I have compiled it to .py file and it works. Now I wanted to implement it into my main class which has a lot of methods based on voice recognition commands. Should I copy all the code from GUI.py into Main.py or shall I just import it somehow and then adjust buttons to start and stop application? It is my first app which I make from scratch and any advice will be helpfull. Python is not my main language so I am not sure how to import one class file into another one and use both classes methods

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you to carefully read the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), and remember to *never* edit the output of `pyuic`, nor try to mimic its contents.

Comment: https://nitratine.net/blog/post/how-to-import-a-pyqt5-ui-file-in-a-python-gui/

Here a step to step guide if you want to use loadUi